# Putting R1C1 formula on variable rows to reference the same column

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to write a code which puts an R1C1 formula into a row’s cells.

The start position of the row’s will vary each time the macro is run. 
Ie. If the macro is run the first time, the formula will be entered into Row B16 as R[-5]C[3]. R[-5] in the case is E12.

However, when the macro is run another time, & its entered into row B25, I still want it to reference to E3, but it references to  E20.

Here is my code

```
Dim cell As Range, MyRange As Range 

Set MyRange = Range("B1:B5000")

For Each cell In MyRange

If cell = " " And cell.Offset(, 1) <> "Record" Then

cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C[3]: SUM(R[-5]C[4])"

End If

Next cell

End With
```

You are right, my code was trying to say `This row - 5, this column + 3: this row -5, this column + 4`
The problem I have is that This row could be any row & I would like to use relative referencing as this formula copies down to the next row
So what I’m trying to do is this

```
Cell B16 = E11+F11
Cell B17 = E12+F12
Cell B18 = E13+F13 etc
```

Then when the macro is run again & start cell is E25, then

```
Cell E25 = E20+F20
Cell E26 = E21+F21
Cell E26= E22+F22 etc
```

So, regardless of which cell the macro points to, it will always start the calculation from `E11+F11`

Comment: Do you already have some code to show?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

Dim cell As Range, MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("B1:B5000")

For Each cell In MyRange

If cell = " " And cell.Offset(, 1) <> "Record" Then

cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-5]C[3]: SUM(R[-5]C[4])"

End If

Next cell

End With

Comment: You can delete this post if you want - I've added the code to your original question.

Comment: You are right, my code was trying to say This row - 5, this column + 3: this row -5, this column + 4 The problem I have is that This row could be any row & I would like to use relative referencing as this formula copies down to the next row So what I’m trying to do is this

Cell B16 = E11+F11
Cell B17 = E12+F12
Cell B18 = E13+F13 etc
Then when the macro is run again & start cell is E25, then

Cell E25 = E20+F20
Cell E26 = E21+F21
Cell E26= E22+F22 etc
So, regardless of which cell the macro points to, it will always start the calculation from E11+F11

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative references in your formula, and the formula won't work as you're trying to say `=SUM(E1:SUM(F1)` if the entered in cell B6.  Any rows higher than that and it will try and reference off the sheet.

To use absolute referencing use `R3C5` (row 3, column 5 = E3).
At best your formula was trying to say `This row - 5, this column + 3: this row -5, this column + 4`

Maybe try `"=SUM(R3C5:R3C4)"` which is the same as `=SUM($E$3:$F$3)`.

Also - `cell = " "` - the cell must contain a single space?  Should it be `cell = ""`?

**Edit**:
In response to your edit - if you want the first formula to always look at E11:F11, and the next to be E12:F12, etc you can use one of these solutions:

To add the formula to all rows in one hit - this doesn't check for a cell with a space:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim lOffset As Long

    Set MyRange = Range("B1:B5000")

    With MyRange
        lOffset = 11 - .Row
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]<>""Record"",SUM(R[" & lOffset & "]C5:R[" & lOffset & "]C6),"""")"
    End With

End Sub
```

To check that each cell has a space in it before adding the formula:

```
Public Sub Test1()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lOffset As Long

    Set MyRange = Range("B30:B5000")

    lOffset = 11 - MyRange.Row
    For Each rCell In MyRange
        If rCell = " " And rCell.Offset(, 1) <> "Record" Then
            rCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & lOffset & "]C5:R[" & lOffset & "]C6)"
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Here's the results for the second code block showing the formula always starts in row 11:
[image]

And if you change the range the formula goes in:
[image]

**Edit 2:**
If rows 20:24 have Record then this will place `=SUM($E11:$F11)` in row 25.    If row 26 has a record then row 27 will have `=SUM($E12:$F12)`

```
Public Sub Test1()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lOffset As Long

    Set MyRange = Range("B20:B30")

    lOffset = 11
    For Each rCell In MyRange
        If rCell = " " And rCell.Offset(, 1) <> "Record" Then
            rCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & lOffset - rCell.Row & "]C5:R[" & lOffset - rCell.Row & "]C6)"
            lOffset = lOffset + 1
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: But you didn't want it always pointing at row 11 - the first formula points at row 11, the next one at row 12, etc.  As you said: _Cell B16 = E11+F11 Cell B17 = E12+F12 Cell B18 = E13+F13 etc_  If I set `MyRange` to B16:B5000 the first formula is `=SUM($D11:$E11)`, the second is `=SUM($D12:$E12)` (ok, increase the columns by 1 C5 & C6 rather than C4 & C5).

Comment: The row number of Col B will vary each time the macro is run. So, could be B16, first time. B20, second time. etc. However, regardless of where the row number falls on , the starting calculation should be E11+F11. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the columns so it's E+F rather than D+E, but the code is doing what you're asking (see screen shots I've added).

Comment: I’m sorry if I’m not explaining myself properly. Using the second screen shot range (“B20:B20”), assuming that when it loops through, it finds records in rows 20 -24. Therefore, will start the calculation from B25. This is where I am having a problem, as the calculation does point to row 11 in this instant. It starts from Row 16.

Comment: ok, I think I'm getting you now.  So it starts in B20, rows 20 - 24 have records but it can put a formula in B25.  This formula in B25 should be `=SUM(E11,F11)`.  Now, if B26 has a record and the next formula is placed in cell B27 - should the formula in B27 be `=SUM(E12,F12)` or `=SUM(E13,F13)`?

Comment: Yes, it starts with B20, if row 20-24 is not empty and have Col C have record, then it places the formula in B25, B26, B27 … to the B50 (or the end of the range)

Yes, I would like to chat privately regarding this, however I’m a new joiner and have only 1 reputation. 
So the site is not allowing me to chat